# RewriteRule with dash or hyphen

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In accordance with the SEO guidelines I am changing pages url from

`website.com/color_red/` (underscore) to

`website.com/color-red/` (dash / hyphen)

/color-red/ must simply produce ?c=red

In .htaccess this works perfectly with underscore:

```
RewriteRule ^color_([^/\.]+)/?$ ?c=$1 [L]
```

not with dash:

```
RewriteRule ^color-([^/\.]+)/?$ ?c=$1 [L]
```

I think dash char must be escaped but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

***1st solution:*** To handle both `_` OR `-` in your URLs then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^color[_-]([^/]*)/?$ ?c=$1 [L]
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you only want to handle `-` in your URLs then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^color-([^/]*)/?$ ?c=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if you want to add a query string to a Uri or after DNS name this should come?

Comment: /color-red/ must simply produce ?c=red

Comment: @DavidePalmieri, I just checked and this worked fine for me, could you please clear your cache once and try? If you have curl command with you, you could check with that too like `curl -IL "http://localhost/color_red/"`, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Does it work also with dash? /colo-red/ (you wrote link with underscore /color_red/)

Comment: @DavidePalmieri, no it wouldn't work. so do you want to look for either of the links like ``http://localhost/color_red/` OR `http://localhost/color-red/` should go to `http://localhost/?c=$1`? Am I right here, kindly confirm and I will edit my code cheers.

Comment: `http://localhost/color-red/` should go to `http://localhost/?c=red`
`http://localhost/color-blue/` should go to `http://localhost/?c=blue`

Comment: @DavidePalmieri, Sure, I have added 2 solutions now, could you please check and let me know if that helps you? cheers.

Comment: 1st and 2nd solutions both works but they pass the final slash `?c=red/`... is there any way to ignore the final slash and pass only `?c=red`? Thanks

Comment: @DavidePalmieri, honestly I have tried to handle it in regex but not sure why its still printing it, let me give it a try and get back to you in a min or so.

Comment: @DavidePalmieri, could you please try my 2nd solution once, but again this will match after `-` to 1st occurrence of `/` considering that you have only 1 `/` coming in your url. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much @RavinderSingh13 finally it works!
I found also an other working solution, do you know which is better?
`RewriteRule ^color[-]([^/\.]+)/?$ ?c=$1 [L]`

Comment: @DavidePalmieri, IMHO I believe with your shown samples my 2nd solution `RewriteRule ^color-([^/]*)/?$ ?c=$1 [L]`(basically we don't want `.` in its negotiation because its not in samples) will be better in your shown samples case, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to escape the hypen/dash char `-` with square brackets `[-]` :

```
RewriteRule ^color[-]([^/\.]+)/?$ ?c=$1 [L]
```